# Perl converts to int wrong but only with specific number

Tags: perl, floating-point, integer

the following perl code converts a float number to the wrong integer number

```
use strict;

my $zahl =297607.22000;
$zahl=$zahl * 100;
print "$zahl\n";
my $text=sprintf ("%017d",$zahl);
print $text;
```

The output of this is :

```
29760722
00000000029760721
```

The thing is, you can change the given number to other numbers and it works.

Any idea what is wrong here or does Perl simply do it wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 8):

This is related to a FAQ ([Why am I getting long decimals](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#Why-am-I-getting-long-decimals-%28eg,-19.9499999999999%29-instead-of-the-numbers-I-should-be-getting-%28eg,-19.95%29?)). `$zahl` is not rounded properly, it is rounded down to the next lower integer.

Comment: Why is it rounded differently in these two examples though?

Comment: @Mat: because int rounds towards zero, and the closest floating point representation to 297607.22000 happens to be something like 297607.21999999997

Comment: @ysth: I understand it's a rounding issue. What I don't understand is why different rules apply to the first `print` statement and the rounding in the `sprintf`.

Comment: The `print` print the value as a real number, so it prints the most accurate value it can, given the limited precision of the underlying representation.  Apparently it does that by rounding.  When you `printf` a real number with `"%d"`, it first converts it from floating-point to an integer, and that conversion truncates.  Try `printf "%f %d\n", 1.9, 1.9`.

Comment: Mat: it is *not* a rounding issue per se, it is a representation issue.  297607.22 is not a representable floating point number; the closest floating point number to it will be either less or more than it.  If less, multiplying by 100 will get you a number slightly less than the integer you expected; if more, it will be slightly more.  If less, int()/%d will give you a different number than you expected, if more, int()/%d will "work".  But in either case int is rounding towards zero.

Answer (score 2):

When you are doing your floating point multiplication by 100 the result will be something like `29760721.9999999963`. Then when you do the `%d` conversion to an integer this is truncated to `29760721`.

Try `sprintf('%.10f', $zahl)` and you should be able to see this.

Comment: It's not rounded at all. It's just truncated.

Answer (score 2):

`22/100` is a periodic number in binary just like 1/3 is a periodic number in decimal. It would take infinite storage to store it exactly in a floating point number.

```
$ perl -e'$_="297607.22000"; $_*=100; printf "%.20f\n", $_'
29760721.99999999627470970154
```

`int` and `sprintf %d` truncate decimals, so you end up with 29760721. `print` and `sprintf %f` round, so you can get the desired result.

```
$ perl -e'$_="297607.22000"; $_*=100; printf "%017.0f\n", $_'
00000000029760722
```

Comment: You have `int` both truncating and rounding.  It only truncates.

Comment: @cjm, Typo. `print` needs a better PR agent! (pun intended) Fixed before I even noticed your message :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to be really careful with floating point numbers and treating them as fixed point.  Due to various conversions that may take place in the builtins, there may be times where one integer conversion is not exactly the same as another.  It appears that this happens many times with `x.22` numbers:

```
use strict;

my $n = 0;
for (0 .. 10_000_000) {
    my $float = 100 * "$_.22";

    my $str = "$float";
    my $int = int $float;

    if ($str ne $int) {
        $n++;
        #say "$float, $str, $int";
    }
}

say "n = $n";
```

which prints

```
n = 76269
```

on my system.

A careful look at the Perl source would be required to see where the exact conversion difference is.

I would recommend that if you are going to be working with fixed point numbers, to convert them all to integers (using a common conversion function, preferably looking at the source numbers as strings), and then work with them all under the `use integer;` pragma which will disable floating point numbers.

Comment: A look at the perl source isn't going to tell you why X.22*100's closest floating point representation is less than it; it just is.

Comment: In fact, it's not even related to Perl. It's a property of floating point numbers, and all languages that use them will exhibit the same behaviour.